# cert-manager do not create new certs

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager

After almost 1 year without a problem, I realized that cert-manager can't produce certificates anymore.

I started seeing this error:

> Error from server: conversion webhook for cert-manager.io/v1alpha2,
> Kind=Certificate failed: Post
> "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s":
> x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time
> 2021-12-05T01:02:15Z is after 2021-12-03T14:15:56Z

I do NOT have a problem with the existing certificates/domains. But, it can't create certs for new domains.

Also,

```
kubectl get cert
```

has the same error output.

What is the recommended solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually deleting secrets `cert-manager-webhook-ca` and `cert-manager-webhook-tls` may work in this case. Cert-manager controller will automatically create the deleted secrets afterwards.

Comment: I deleted the secrets in cert-manager worksapace with the following command kubectl delete secret cert-manager-webhook-ca  cert-manager-webhook-tls. After that, I deleted the deployment and did it again. It created the certs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest updating the version of **Cert-manager** you are running.

```
helm install \
  cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace mynamespace \
  --version v0.15.1 \
  --set installCRDs=true
```

do not forget to install the CRD.

`Cert-manager` supports the latest two releases only which are currently **1.5** and **1.6** while **1.7** is an upcoming release.

Refer to the Release document [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/supported-releases/) and you can also refer to the reported [issue](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2752) for more information.